# Not available Case Information fields in report type

Tags: fields, object, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I'm trying 2 Report types and I have problems with fields availability.

REPORT TYPE 1: Cases standard report type. With this, I can access to 'Case information' fields like Age, Opened Date, and so on.

REPORT TYPE 2: Custom Report type with Cases, services and service appointments. With this, I cannot access to 'Case information' fields. So, for example, if I want to include 'Age' field, I cannot do it.

Why it's happening? Is due to REPORT 1 is standard and REPORT 2 is custom?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_report_type_guidelines.htm&type=5), age field is available on the Case reports using standard report type but this won't be available on custom report type.

As a workaround, create a custom formula field on case object and include on custom report.

```
IF(IsClosed,  (ClosedDate - CreatedDate),   (NOW() - CreatedDate))
```

Check more details on case age formula [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000341512&type=1).

Also, review steps mentioned [Fields Are Not Available to Add to a Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321283&type=1).

Thanks